# Using curl to get data from a website

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use cURL to get train information from http://www.indianrail.gov.in/know_Station_Code.html .
I have the following PHP code :

```
<?php
$fields = array(
            'lccp_src_stncode_dis'=>'MANGAPATNAM-+MUM',
            'lccp_src_stncode'=>'MUM',
            'lccp_dstn_stncode_dis‌'=>'AMBALA+CITY-+UBC',
            'lccp_dstn_stncode'=>'UBC',
            'lccp_classopt'=>'SL',
            'lccp_day'=>'17',
            'lccp_month'=>'8',
            'CurrentMonth'=>'7',
            'CurrentDate'=>'17',
            'CurrentYear'=>'2015'
        );

$fields_string = '';         //defining an empty string
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
    $temp = $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    $fields_string.$temp;
}
rtrim($fields_string,'&');      //removing the last '&' from the generated string

$curl = curl_init('http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_srcdest_cgi_date.cgi');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

The problem is that I get this output on my browser window :

```
boolean false
```

I tried using `var_dump(curl_error($curl))` and I got the following output :

```
string 'Empty reply from server' (length=23)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `var_dump(curl_error($curl);` to show error

Comment: On using that I got : string 'Empty reply from server' (length=23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution :

```
$fields = array(
    'lccp_src_stncode_dis'=>'MANGAPATNAM-+MUM',
    'lccp_src_stncode'=>'MUM',
    'lccp_dstn_stncode_dis?'=>'AMBALA+CITY-+UBC',
    'lccp_dstn_stncode'=>'UBC',
    'lccp_classopt'=>'SL',
    'lccp_day'=>'17',
    'lccp_month'=>'8',
    'CurrentMonth'=>'7',
    'CurrentDate'=>'17',
    'CurrentYear'=>'2015'
);

$fields_string = '';         //defining an empty string
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
    $temp = $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; // urlencode
    $fields_string.= $temp; // equal sign
    }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$header = array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
        'Accept-Language: en-us;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        );
$curl = curl_init('http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_srcdest_cgi_date.cgi');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header); //server require
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.indianrail.gov.in/know_Station_Code.html'); //server require
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13'); //server require
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
//close connection
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks...finally it worked :) Does the value of CURLOPT_USERAGENT changes for different PCs such as Macs or LINUX?

Comment: While it seems to fix the issue, this answer doesn't provide an explanation about what the problem was and how it was fixed.

Comment: I did see it. I'm saying it could be a bit more obvious and detailed for the benefit of future visitors who might run into a similar issue but for whom this particular code would not apply.

Comment: Is there any way that I can parse only the required information from the response instead of being redirected to the website page?

Comment: Is using curl_exec($curl) to store the resulting information in a variable same as using file_get_contents('URL') to store a webpage in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to solve this problem.

**1. cURL:**

I believe what you were missing is `http_build_query()`. This internally converts an array into a HTTP query format. Like this:

```
$fields = array(
        'lccp_src_stncode_dis'=>'MANGAPATNAM-+MUM',
        'lccp_src_stncode'=>'MUM',
        'lccp_dstn_stncode_dis‌'=>'AMBALA+CITY-+UBC',
        'lccp_dstn_stncode'=>'UBC',
        'lccp_classopt'=>'SL',
        'lccp_day'=>'17',
        'lccp_month'=>'8',
        'CurrentMonth'=>'7',
        'CurrentDate'=>'17',
        'CurrentYear'=>'2015'
    );

$post_fields = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init($API_URL);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip, deflate");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r(response);
```

**2. Postman**

This is one of the best tools for the problem you have. here is how this works:

Install Postman on your chrome browser. you can get it [from the chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop).
Get the postman Interceptor [from the same chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo).

Once you have these two, follow these steps to get your PHP code for all the requests your browser makes:

1) Turn on the Interceptor

[image]

2) Open the Postman App:

[image]

3) Turn on the request capturing feature

[image]

4) Make your call on the Indian railways website

[image]

5) You'll get your Entire call, including headers and the post fields capturen in postman.

[image]

6) Click on **Generate Code** button and choose PHP -> cURL. You'll get th PHP code that makes the exact same request as the browser.

[image]

You can copy this code into the clipboard and use it as you wish.

**3. Use a Library**

There are libraries that you can use which handles all the errors. [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) is one such framework. You can find it's documentation [here](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I used 1st method but still got the same output...however 2nd method was helpful. Only the problem now is that I am being redirected to the website on executing the query I got from the app and it displays there : Following ERROR was encountered in your Query Processing The Station Code is Invalid Please Try Again Server : KESHAV